# Summation involving Binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

$$S(m,k)=\sum_{n=m}^{k}(-1)^n\binom{n}{m}$$
Is possible to get closed form solution of this sum?
We know $$T(m,k)=\sum_{n=m}^{k}\binom{n}{m}=\binom{k+1}{m+1}$$
But what if the sign alternates?

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression but is not a closed form
$$S(m,k)=\sum_{n=m}^{k}(-1)^n\binom{n}{m}=(-1)^k \binom{k+1}{m} \, _2F_1(1,k+2;k+2-m;-1)+(-1)^m\, 2^{-(m+1)}$$ where appears [the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: I got that using Mathematica. Is there simple way to evaluate hypergeometric series at z = -1 for this case?